# Kill Application on RM UI has latency

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I want to kill a MR process after it has been running for hours, then I click **Kill Application** on the  RM Web UI
But sometime the job does not End immediately.

1. The YARN cluster (RM) is not busy
2. MR with small dataset has low latency

[image]

Comment: This is expected behavior for a large job. Each nodemanager in the cluster needs to be be able to accept network requests from the ResourceManager and stop the associated JVM processes. If the _nodemanagers_ are busy, there will be latency (which they are if they are processing many jobs)

Comment: Many THANKS! I'm much clear about it now.